# Why am I getting a namespace error with Manufaktura Library

Tags: c#, wpf, musicxml

I am attempting to use this library 
Manufaktura to draw music notation in a WPF application.

I have the using statement that I need according to the instructions on [this page](http://manufaktura-programow.pl/xaml-controls-tutorial)

```
using Manufaktura.Controls;
using Manufaktura.Model;
using Manufaktura.Music;
using Manufaktura.Controls.WPF;
using Manufaktura.Model.MVVM;
```

I have the appropriate dlls referenced in the solution explorer of Visual Studio as well.

When I used the code sample I am getting two errors (three but 2 are basically the same).

Code from Instruction:

```
public class TestDataViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private Score data;

    public Score Data
    {
        get { return data;  }
        set { data = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => Data); }
    }

    public void LoadTestData()
    {

    }
}
```

Errors:

> Error  1   The type or namespace name 'Score' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And

> Error  3   The type arguments for method 'Manufaktura.Model.MVVM.ViewModel.OnPropertyChanged(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to **reference** the libraries instead of adding using statements.  So, right-click your project's references and then "Add Reference..." for each class library listed in the documentation.

FYI, the second error is just a consequence of the Score type not being found. Once the complier knows about Score, it should go away.

**Update**: I inspected the Manufaktura.Controls class library and the Score class is in the namespace Manufaktura.Controls.Model.  So try adding a using statement for that namespace too.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I did in fact add the references in the solution explorer already. I am new to this and figured I would inspect it. In ActionScript 3 you can add namespaces and all subsidiaries with the syntax: Example.com.*; is there an equivalent facility in C#?

Comment: C# doesn't have such a feature unfortunately.  Here's a good [SO thread on C# namespace using statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023465/importing-nested-namespaces-automatically-in-c-sharp). One thing you might not be aware of is that Visual Studio can automatically add any missing using statements for you. In VS2015 you can right-click on the Score class and select "Quick Actions...".  The first available action is to add "using Manufaktura.Controls.Model;" to fix the error.  This will only work if you have already referenced the assembly though.