# Java package vs c# assemblies

Tags: c#, java, assemblies, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a Java package the equivalent of a .Net assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629291/is-a-java-package-the-equivalent-of-a-net-assembly)

I was comparing the access modifiers in Java and C#.

In java the default access allows access to the class being modified to everything in the package that the class is in.  In C# the internal access modifier allows access to the class being modified to everything in the assembly that the class is in.

Are Java packages the same as C# assemblies, if not what is the difference.

Comment: C# is Component Oriented when Java is Object Oriented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are not same. As also mentioned in the [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629291/is-a-java-package-the-equivalent-of-a-net-assembly). The best comparison would be with a Java ARchive (Jar) file. Java uses packages to control the namespace, and is very similar to C#'s Namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to think of a C# assembly as a sealed jar or an OSGI package. A Java `package` is closer to a C# `namespace`, although none of these concepts map across the two languages perfectly.